# No-op lambda

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have an event on one of my classes that I want to attach a handler to. However, I don't need the handler to do anything, as I am just testing the behaviour of the class with handlers attached or not.

The event signature is as follows:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Foo;
```

So I want to do something like:

```
myClass.Foo += ();
```

However this isn't a valid lambda expression.  What is the most succinct way to express this?

Comment: Fun fact: you can also attach empty delegates to events so that you don't need to do a null check before invoking the event a la http://stackoverflow.com/a/1431993/1508243

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
myClass.Foo += (s,e) => {};
```

or

```
myClass.Foo += delegate {};
```

Answer (score 11):

```
(x,y) => {} //oops forgot the params
```

OK?  :)

Or

```
delegate {}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
myClass.Foo += delegate {};
```

Answer (score 6):

Rather than attach a delegate afterwards, the more common way is to do assign it immediately:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Foo = delegate {};
```

I prefer using the anonymous method syntax over a lambda expression here as it will work with various different signatures (admittedly not those with `out` parameters or return values).

Comment: Yes, but in this case I do not want to assign a default handler.

Comment: Fair enough. (Personally I put one in just about every event I declare these days :)

Comment: In this case the class needs to have a different behaviour if it has no handlers attached to the event. If nobody is listening to it it mumbles quietly to itself :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
myClass.Foo += (s,e) => {};
```

Answer (score 1):

Attach the event via a lambda like such:

```
myClass.Foo += (o, e) => {
    //o is the sender and e is the EventArgs
};
```